# Can you wire a regular 120/125v recepticle with two hots?

Tags: 120-240v

I have some LED Grow lights that can take 120/240/277 volt of power. The power cord is a a regular 125v plug w/ ground. My question is can I wire a regular 125v recepticle with two hots (1 on brass and 1 on silver) and a ground to a double 20amp breaker and make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: You can rewire the _circuit_ to be 240v, and use a properly rated 240v receptacle.  Everything on the circuit will be 240v, which may or may not be ok.  It's a little unclear what you want.

Comment: It sounds like you want to serve 240 volts to a standard outlet. That would be colossally dangerous to anyone happening upon it later. It's not allowed for that reason. Also, the light is probably expecting 240 or 277 volts _on one leg_, not as a two-leg 240.

Comment: If they are LEDs then you probably be making more work for yourself than any savings to going to 240.  Besides burning down the house/destroying other 120 devices.

Comment: Thanks for your input. This project is mine and no one else will use it so im not worried about others using a 120v outlet not knowing it's actually 240v. If i did wire a correct 240 outlet how should i go about converting the led fixture to be able to plug into 240 outlet?

Comment: Yeah, that's how the sad story usually begins. Don't do it.

Comment: *update* the circuit im using would be dedicated to lights only. 120v outlet will be on seperate circuit for other applicances.

Comment: Should just need to match plug design to outlet design, mainly the way prongs are placed

Comment: You need to revise to provide more information. We know nothing about your light.

Comment: This makes no sense. If it isn't wired yet, do it right with hot and neutral and ground 120v. If it is wired then it is either cable black white which is standard for 120v neutral or it is two non white colors in conduit and you can add a white neutral.

Comment: How many watts do these lights use?

Comment: You're not the only human.  You DO make mistakes. And you will move out of that house someday, and it won't be bulldozed when you do.  And you're not thinking reasonably, because you're in too much of a hurry to 'get r done'.  Slow down, take a breath, de-stubborn-ize and listen to experts, and then do it right.  *Isn't that what you came here for?*

Comment: If the lights accept 120v, why not use it?  Do you need more wattage?

Answer (score 5):

### Absolutely not!

I get it.  The NEMA 5-15 socket is the only type you are familiar with, but applying the wrong voltage is *dangerous* for reasons you're not thinking about (because you're in too much of a hurry to 'get there').

### Doing it right is *easy*

(it just doesn't seem that way because it's 'new to you').

Actually, there's a cornucopia of socket types, and there's a right one for *exactly what you're trying to do*.  Two, actually :)

[image]

Install the third or fourth one (both are allowed on a 240V/20A circuit).

Change the plug on the cord to a NEMA 6-15 type.

*"That was easy"*

P.S. Remember that when using /2 cable for 240V, you must use electrical tape to re-mark the white wire black or red on both ends.

See? Doing it safe and legal isn't that hard.